# Where are messages during VM boot under Gnome-Boxes stored?

Tags: boot, gnome-boxes

During Win-10 Booting Under Gnome-Boxes, a couple of messages are shown for a second or less.  The VM starts fine but I'd like to see what the messages are saying.

Where are these messages saved?  On my Ubuntu 20.04 system or am I seeing something that Windows is reporting?  I got the feeling they were like bios messages you might see when restarting a real PC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a virtual machine in the GNOME Boxes overview will open a menu. Click "Properties" and go to the "System" tab. There you can find the "Troubleshooting Logs" button. The messages you are looking for are possible there.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look at it.